# Windows Metro App Filtering Listview and showing specific data from list?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I am not aware if there is any "callback" to Listview creation so that i can display very specific type of data from the List i have.
What i know is that only Complete List can be bound to the ListView, but how can i put some checking to it like its done in iOS by the help of Datasource Delegate.

Anyone ?

Comment: Why not just bind to an empty list and then add to it?

Comment: Can you please explain a little more ? thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "Complete List"

Comment: I meant populated List which has some data out of which i want to show  specific data. For example : if i want to check a boolean value and display something different based on that OR assign color to first row and 4th row in ListView.How do i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering and grouping has traditionally be done with **CollectionViewSource**. Unfortunately, **CollectionViewSource** no longer has the **Filter** event or the **GroupDescriptions** property. It may seem like filtering and grouping are unsupported, but both can still be achieved using LINQ.

In your Xaml, add a **CollectionViewSource** in the Resources section of your page. Make sure IsSourceGrouped is set to true:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>

    <!--
        Collection of grouped items displayed by this page, bound to a subset
        of the complete item list because items in groups cannot be virtualized
    -->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="GroupsCV" Source="{Binding Groups}" IsSourceGrouped="True" />

</common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>
```

Now, the **CollectionViewSource** (GroupsCV) should be set as the ItemsSource for your GridView:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupsCV}}" />
```

Notice that **CollectionViewSource** is bound to a property called **Groups**. This property is part of my ViewModel. The value returned by the **Groups** property will be the result of a LINQ query. This confused me at first because I didn't know what *type* the property should return. I settled on an enumerable grouping of comparable items. This pretty much works with any LINQ query of any type.

So, in your ViewModel (or whatever your DataContext is) add the following property:

```
private IEnumerable<IGrouping<IComparable, TItem>> groups;
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<IComparable, TItem>> Groups
{
    get { return groups; }
    set { SetProperty(ref groups, value); }
}
```

Now, whenever you want to change the grouping or the filter, just set the Groups property equal to a LINQ query like so:

```
Groups = from i in musicItems
            group i by i.Genre into g
            orderby g.Key
            select g;
```

LINQ does great with known property names, but what about letting the user pick from a list of property names and dynamically grouping by that property? Well, the only requirement for LYNQ to be able to create a group is that whatever you pass it must implement **IComparable**.

Here's a little extension method that takes the name of a property as a string and returns an **IComparable**:

```
static public IComparable GetComparableValue<T>(this T item, string propName) where T : class
{
    return (IComparable)typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(propName).GetValue(item, null);
}
```

With that in place, you can do a dynamic query by property name like this:

```
string groupByPropertyName = "Artist";

Groups = from i in musicItems
group i by i.GetComparableValue(groupByPropertyName) into g
orderby g.Key
select g;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: P.S. I was showing how to create groups there, but you can easily filter as well. On the 2nd line of the query (the line after the from) add a where clause. You can filter on any property and should even be able to use the GetComparableValue trick to dynamically filter on a property by name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of the exact scenario you're trying to solve, but there are ways to create a filtered view on an existing source of data. You also don't say if this is XAML or JavaScript. I'm gonna answer the JavaScript part.

Obviously, you could just re-wrap the data you've got to the form you want it.

You can also choose a number of other options:

- Use WinJS.Binding.List, along with the createFilter method. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700774.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700741.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465464.aspx

- [implement your own data source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh770849.aspx)

Comment: dhopton its XAML and C#.I am not using JS. Can you please provide help on that.

Comment: That's just a normal IList type API, and you should be able to do normal C#-y, WPF-y methods to make all of that work. No experise from me on that :(